# ITextSharp: after rotating PDF, my template is rotated aswell, how to prevent this

Tags: c#, templates, pdf, rotation, itext

I am using ITextSharp library to add a footer to a PDF. I want to create an additional function which allows me to rotate the PDF, because sometimes it is not in the right direction when opening it. However, when I rotate the PDF, the footer is rotated aswell. Of course I don't want this, the footer should always be at the bottom.

I have following code to create the PDF:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numpages; i++)
{
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i+1);
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    document.NewPage();
}
```

And I also override the 'OnEndPage':

```
//some code
PdfContentByte cb;
//some more code
cb = writer.DirectContent;
//some more code
 public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

        PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(writer.PageNumber);
        int desiredRot = rotation;
        PdfNumber rot = pageDict.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
        pageDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(desiredRot));
        writer.AddPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, pageDict.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE));

        // select the font properties
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);

        string dateText = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        string signText = "Sign:";
        string testText = "Att. " + evidenceID + ": " + testReference;
        string pageText = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of " + numberOfPages;

        Point datePosition;
        Point signPosition;
        Point testTextPosition;
        Point pagePosition;
        if (isOrientationLandscape())
        {
            datePosition = new Point(45 + bf.GetWidth(dateText) / 155, footerHeight + 13);
            signPosition = new Point(45 + bf.GetWidth(signText) / 155, footerHeight);
            testTextPosition = new Point(385, footerHeight);
            pagePosition = new Point(700, footerHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            datePosition = new Point(45 + bf.GetWidth(dateText) / 155, footerHeight + 13);
            signPosition = new Point(45 + bf.GetWidth(signText) / 155, footerHeight);
            testTextPosition = new Point(300, footerHeight);
            pagePosition = new Point(510, footerHeight);
        }

        // write the text in the pdf content
        cb.BeginText();
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, dateText, datePosition.X, datePosition.Y, 0);
        cb.EndText();

        cb.BeginText();
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, signText, signPosition.X, signPosition.Y, 0);
        cb.EndText();

        cb.BeginText();
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, testText, testTextPosition.X, testTextPosition.Y, 0);
        cb.EndText();

        cb.BeginText();
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, pageText, pagePosition.X, pagePosition.Y, 0);
        cb.EndText();

    }
```

[image: Template rotates as pdf rotates]

**EDIT:**

I solved it with a work-around, by just rotating the text itself and recalculating the coördinates:

```
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, pageText, pagePosition.X, pagePosition.Y, rotation);
```

and

```
private Point getCoordinatesInRotation(Point originalPoint, Rotation rotation, PdfDictionary pageDict)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageDict);
            Point newPoint = new Point();
            switch (rotation)
            {
                case Rotation.rotation0:
                    return originalPoint;
                case Rotation.rotation90:
                    newPoint.X = (int)pageSize.GetTop(2) - originalPoint.Y;
                    newPoint.Y = originalPoint.X;
                    return newPoint;
                case Rotation.rotation180:
                    newPoint.X = originalPoint.X;
                    newPoint.Y = (int)pageSize.GetTop(2) - originalPoint.Y;
                    return newPoint;
                case Rotation.rotation270:
                    newPoint.X = originalPoint.Y;
                    newPoint.Y = (int)pageSize.GetTop(2) - originalPoint.X;
                    return newPoint;
                default:
                    return originalPoint;
            }
        }
```

It is not 100% perfect yet (the text is a bit moved to 1 side when rotating), but it will do for now..

Comment: As an aside: Is adding header and footer all you change? In that case using a PdfStamper would be much better.

Comment: Yes, that is all actually. Why is it better to use PdfStamper then?

Comment: *"Why is it better to use PdfStamper then?"* - First of all, your way of copying is lossy: it drops all annotations (e.g. form field widgets). And it drops all document properties (e.g. meta data and document level file attachments). And it wraps the page content in a container for which there is a maximum nesting level (so you may drop visible content if your original already made use of the maximum nesting level). Furthermore, using a PdfStamper requires less own coding.

Comment: OK thank you, I will try using PdfStamper then

Comment: Have you had success trying to use the `PdfStamper`? If you had, you might want to create an answer to your question to that effect. If you had not but still are interested, please say so. If you had not and are not interested anymore, you might want to remove the question.